# Is it possible to include content from one word doc into a second word document that dynamically updates?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using MS Word 2013

I have one document that has general instructions that I would like to include multiple documents. I can add it fairly easily using Word's "Text from File" feature. However it seems like it's little more than a replacement for copy and paste.

Is it possible to include content from word document "A" into word document "B" which will update document "B" when document "A" is updated?

Comment: This would be a cool thing, but I don't think that it's possible.  The only thing that I can think of is to merge the two documents, but that's a manual process.

Comment: Can't you use `{INCLUDETEXT}`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at Master Documents. Master documents allow you to include other documents, they are designed for complex reports where many people may need to work on different parts of the document.

It isn't quite how you describe things. The master contains references to it's children. The easiest way is to use the Outline view and designate specific headings as being child documents.

It is dependent on having a well structured document.

See:

- [About Master Documents](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/about-master-documents-HP005234679.aspx)
- However! Note the serious health warnings [here](http://www.addbalance.com/word/masterdocuments.htm#PageStart). Make sure you keep lots of backup copies to handle document corruptions.